# What is DynamoDB's server-side timeout if any?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm aware I can set various client-side timeouts in my DynamoDb client. But what are the server-side timeouts?

For example, if I set a clientExecutionTimeout or requestTimeout of 1sec, will Dynamodb continue to work even after my client has timed out? Or does my clientConfiguration timeouts get sent to DynamoDb such that as soon as my client's timeout is reached, Dynamodb throws a timeout exception and stops processing on its end?

Also, if Dynamodb will process my request until my clientConfiguration timeout is reached, what's the maximum value I can set for my timeout? Can I set an hour long timeout and keep a DynamoDb node waiting forever in the rare event it can't process my request for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question, and one I don't think you're going to get a definitive answer to, as AWS don't publish the information.

From my personal experience, there is no obvious timeout. I have run scans that have taken hours to return, and that works fine.

AWS publish all of the [exceptions that DynamoDB can throw](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html), and there is nothing about request timeouts.

Presumably the underlying infrastructure could timeout a connection, but it would seem a massive oversight by AWS if they didn't mention this, or have DynamoDB timeout the connection first and throw a nice exception.

So admittedly its not definitive, but I'm fairly sure DynamoDB never times out a request on their side.